# External iframe source-code (Firebug, Selenium...)

Tags: firefox, iframe, selenium, firebug, xul

1) I have an external iframe, and I wondered how Selenium or Firebug managed to overcome the Same Origin Policy to retrieve source code (or even execute some JavaScript)

As for Firebug, I think this has to do with cd(frames[0]) command. In Selenium, you can access content in the iframe with an xpath link, but I have no idea how it internally works.

2) Is it possible to use similar methods outside of a Firefox plugin?

3) What about IE? (or Chrome, but it is way less important)

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that Selenium and Firebug get around it is buy running in the browser chrome rather than in the JavaScript sandbox. For example, calling *firefox calls the slightly less secure version of the browser, by less secure I mean it is running in more of the browser chrome than your average user, and can do the relevant calls.

Addons and Extensions to Firefox run in this context too so can access things in the same way.

Comment: So, is it possible to call the 'relaxed' mode inside a website? I didn't find lot of information, can you show me a link please ? There is no such mode in IE, Safari or Chrome?

Comment: its how the browser is started that gives you this access. So IE has IEHTA and Firefox has Chrome. If you have javascript you can't access it from a webpage because it hits the sandbox, and to be honest, rightly so.

Comment: From what I understand, I can make a greasemonkey user script to realize what I want (it seems cross-platform after proper extension is installed). Otherwise, how to start FF in Chrome mode?

Comment: Running Greasemonkey is going to running in the Browser Chrome. The Selenium source code will tell how to do it.